# What will be the process of statistical analysis with Survey data?

Tags: anova, data-visualization, dataset, survey

I have the survey data of sales force satisfaction and dis-satisfaction . In this data set,there are three to five sub-questions inside to one question. I want to know how can i start the statistical analysis on this data set and what will be the initial steps to go forward through analysis? How can we find the correlation of one question with others and then many one?

In the case of sub-questions which are linked with main question, How will we determine which question or group of the questions affect more to the main question and what will be the correlation?

Answer (score 1):

The first question to answer is, how were your questions designed and tested before deployment? The phrasing -- and even the order -- of questions can have an impact on your results. I assume, from the fact that survey professionals aren't analyzing the results that there were no survey professionals involved in the creation of the survey, which is going to compromise your results.

The second question is, whose opinions are you trying to determine, and how representative of those people are the surveys you got back? If you sent out 500 surveys and got 20 back, do those 20 people really represent your target well? Are there any factors that would cause them to respond -- and most people not to respond -- that are not shared by your target? If you surveyed the sales force in London, are they really representative of your nationwide sales force? Are people with issues more likely to have filled out a web survey asking for comments than people who feel things are going fine?

If you can't answer those two questions well, anything else you do will only give the aura of statistics, not the reality.

After that, the next question is what do you mean by "questions" and "sub-questions"? Are they [likert-scale-style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likert_scale) questions? Ranking questions? It's hard to tell what you have from your brief description.

Taking a step back, what are you trying to do? It sounds like you're saying how you want to do something ("correlations") instead of what questions you're trying to answer. You'll get the best answers here if you describe what data you have (with examples where possible) and then describe the question you're trying to answer and let the experts tell you how to do it.